# if controller for OR Condition in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am working on a scenario where we need to do an action when status is either FAILED or DID_NOT_START, below are the mention status

"status": "DID_NOT_START",
"status": "FAILED",
"status": "STARTED",
"status": "IN_PROGRES",
"status": "SUCCEEDED",

we used regular expression extractor for correlation with match no as 0(Zero for random variable need to be picked), [regular expression extractor plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doKzg.png)

i used below mentioned statements but not worked, please help

```
"${status}" == "FAILED" || "${status}" == "DID_NOT_START"
"${status}" == "FAILED" | "${status}" == "DID_NOT_START"
"${status}" == "FAILED" && "${status}" == "DID_NOT_START"
```

[Ifcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3MJw.png)

we need to do execute particular transaction when status is either FAILED or DID_NOT_START, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is `"${status}" == "FAILED" || "${status}" == "DID_NOT_START"` however you cannot use it in the If Controller per se.

[If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) executes its children if the [Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) used in the condition input evaluates to `true`

So you need to wrap the statement into i.e. __jexl3() function and it will "work"

```
${__jexl3("${status}" == "FAILED" || "${status}" == "DID_NOT_START",)}
```

[image]

If it still "not worked" use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to ensure that your `status` variable exists and has the anticipated value